# Excel Nest Sub Table Where IDs are Equal

Tags: excel

It is possible to nest a sub table in Excel so that I can expand an item and see the sub items. As example is that I have a list of Clients in one table and I want to see their purchases in another. Each Client has an ID and in the Purchases table, each purchase notes the Client ID. I would like to have a single table where you can click and see the purchases by client.

Thanks,

K.

Comment: Have you considered PivotTables at all? http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html

Comment: Yes, but I need to maintain all the columns and data similar to a table, not just a column.

Comment: If you create a pivot table, then double click on a number in the results, it will show all the details that make up that number.

Answer (score 1):

I would use vlookup to bring over the purchases information into the same row as the relevant Client ID, or bring over the client information into the relevant row in the purchases information.

I would use a filter to sort ascending based on Client #.

I would then use subtotal to sum the purchases at each change in client ID. I would then use the Make Table commands on the range.

This will enable you to collapse or expand on the Client #'s purchases.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @AstroCB I have edited the answer to show a workflow. The "question" does not really have a question in it, but I appreciate the point.

Comment: I arrived here from a review queue: your answer was flagged as "Very Low Quality" for its length and content. In its original state, your answer was more like commentary than it was an answer to the question, but I appreciate your effort to improve it.

Comment: Thanks, I will test that tomorrow

Comment: Here is my current setup. I have two tables in two separate sheets. Sheet two has the multiple purchases. How can I get each one to be a distinct row under the client. If I use VLOOKUP, it doesn't seem to return multiples. I know I am missing something

Comment: I would use a vlookup in the purchases table to bring in the relevant client table information, not a vlookup in the client table to bring in the purchases information.